# VSCode - Disable selection on auto-complete suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I use autocomplete, VSCode automatically puts whatever I type in a selection, it didn't happen before and it only started happening recently.

Here's what happens:
I type something like this and suggestion comes up:
[image]

Then I press enter to auto complete:
[image]

All of this is fine, but when I start typing in the quotes:
[image]

VSCode automatically puts my text in a selection. This causes multiple problems. Suggestions get disabled in selection and I have to press Esc everytime I want the selection disabled.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was already answered by @Anton Solomin and @devanil. The issue is VS code auto-suggestion is not working when text is highlighted, because  some of your code snippet is preventing quick suggestion by VS code.
So just tell VS code that don't disable quick suggestion if some snippets askes you to do it.

Go to VScode settings page, in settings search bar type editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions

Uncheck Controls whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestion